# How to set the origin at bottom left in 3d

Tags: c++, opengl, isometric

I want to draw a cube of side 40 at bootom left corner. my glortho function is

```
 glOrtho(0,      // left
        1000,  // right
        0, // bottom
        1000,      // top
        0,      // zNear
        1000       // zFar
        );
```

and lenght of x,y,z axis is up to 1000. so cube should be at bottom left and dimensions should be as i given. and what should be the gluLookAt(); function. I am not getting correct output. If there is any mistakes in the code, correct it and what function should add to the code.

```
#include <gl/glut.h> 
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#else
#endif


void display();
void specialKeys();


double rotate_y=0; 
double rotate_x=0;


void display(){

//  Clear screen and Z-buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Reset transformations
 glLoadIdentity();

 // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
  glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );



  // side - FRONT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );  
  glVertex3f(  0, 0, 0);      
  glVertex3f( 40,0,0);      
  glVertex3f(40,40,0  );     
  glVertex3f(0,40,0 );      

  glEnd();

  //  side - BACK
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,0.0,1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0,0,40 );
  glVertex3f(  0,40,40);
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );   
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glEnd();   

  //  side - RIGHT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - LEFT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,40,0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,40 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - TOP
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  0.0,0.0,1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0,40,0);
  glVertex3f( 0,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,40 );
  glVertex3f( 40,40,0 );
  glEnd();

  //  side - BOTTOM
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  1.0,  0.5,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,0 );
  glVertex3f(  40,0,0 );
  glVertex3f( 40,0,40 );
  glVertex3f( 0,0,40);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

}
 void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluOrtho2D(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
    glOrtho(0,      // left
        1000,  // right
        0, // bottom
        1000,      // top
        0,      // zNear
        1001       // zFar
        );
        gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 0.0); 
}

void specialKeys( int key, int x, int y ) {

  //  Right arrow - increase rotation by 5 degree
  if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    rotate_y += 5;

  //  Left arrow - decrease rotation by 5 degree
  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    rotate_y -= 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    rotate_x += 5;

  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    rotate_x -= 5;

  //  Request display update
  glutPostRedisplay();

}


  int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
  glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
  // Create window
  glutCreateWindow("Awesome Cube");

  //  Enable Z-buffer depth test
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You screwed up your transformations. In `Init()` you set the current matrix mode to `GL_PROJECTION` and load some ortho matrix. Then you multiply the lookAt matrix onto this. This is wrong in principle, as the lookAt matrix should be applied to the `GL_MODELVIEW` stack. (The lookAt parameters you chose actually result in an identity lookAt matrix, so that call has no effect, but that is only a side note).

However, the real error is in `display()`. There you have `glLoadIdentity()` which will just overwrite your previous matrix with an identity matrix, so you lose the Ortho transform you did set up, since you still have `GL_PROJECTION` matrix stack active.

The correct way would be something like:

```
void init()
{
    // ... your other stuff
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( /* your ortho params */ );
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // switch back to the modelView matrix stack
}

void display()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt( /* your Lookat parameters */ );
    glRotate/Scale/Translate(...); // your local transformations
    // ...
}
```

Note that *all of that stuff* is completely *deprecated* and has been *removed* from the core profile of modern OpenGL versions. When learing OpenGL nowadays, you should consider not learning that old cruft from 20 years ago.

Comment: thanks.i have add glOrtho(0, // left 1000, // right 0, // bottom 1000, // top 0, // zNear 1000 // zFar ); function.and gluLookAt( 0,0,20,0,0,0,0,1000,0 ); as you explain. is the glulookat function is correct or not. can u tell me what should be the gluLookAt() function. i want to give the user input as i have given it to the 2d objects and it works. but now i am not getting the desire output please help.

Comment: Why did you change the lookat parameters? With the new ones in the comment, you will look away from your object.